# R: how to change title of plot in lineChart

Tags: r, charts, quantmod

Is there an easy way to make the title "General Electric" instead of "GE"?

**chart.R**

```
library(quantmod)
getSymbols("GE")
lineChart(GE)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use the `name` argument

```
lineChart(GE, name = "General Electric")
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a full example if anyone needs it using the new chart_Series().

```
# create a pdf with titles
# R --silent --vanilla < c.r
suppressWarnings(suppressMessages(library(quantmod)))
options("getSymbols.warning4.0"=FALSE)
options("getSymbols.yahoo.warning"=FALSE)

# list of stocks
s= c("IBM", "AAPL", "GE", "GM")
# get symbols from yahoo
symbols <- list (getSymbols(s, source = "yahoo"))

# create a PDF
pdf(file = "out.pdf")
par(mfrow = c( 4, 2 ) )
chart_Series(IBM, name="IBM")
chart_Series(AAPL, name="Apple")
chart_Series(GE, name="General Electric")
chart_Series(GM, name="General Motors")
dev.off()
```